# What is the FWDN mode?

Tags: recovery-mode

I accidentally pressed a button when turning on my android tablet and it says (typos included):

```
The Device enter FWDN Mode
Please Connect USB to PC or Reset
The Device Waitting........
```

What's the FWDN Mode?

Comment: **F** irm **w** are **D** ow **n** load ?

Comment: What device btw?

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment in the above, I would gauge a guess, its some sort of a **F** *irm* **W** *are* **D** *ow* **n** *load*

A specialized mode particular to that device to enable updating - think of OTA firmware update but using some proprietary software to download the firmware - possibly radio baseband, or a ROM update...